# Long key press and swipe in ListView in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-listview

I have a screen where I am creating a `ListView`. For Android I want to implement "long key press". For iOS I want "swipe gesture".

For long key press and swipe I have to show 3 options:

`Delete | Delete All | More...`

How to do that.

Comment: I have not injected this block code in my code, but I got the idea that I have to use Dismissible and GestureDetector to handle long key press and swipe.

Comment: I already did that last day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your listitem UI in a GetureDetector for Android and use the onLongTap callback. For iOS you can wrap your listitem UI in a Dissmissable widget. A simple extraction should help with that.

Have your UI in a function that returns only your UI for the item, then outside wrap it with the above mentioned based on the platform.

```
// import platform helpers
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show defaultTargetPlatform;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show TargetPlatform;


// determine your platform
 final isIOS = defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS;


// return your appropriate wrapper
isIOS 
? Dismissible(
  child: _getListItemUi(),
) 
: GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: () {
  },
  child: _getListItemUi()
);

Widget _getListItemUi() {
  return Container(child: Text('List Item UI'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To give you an idea you can do this.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bool isIos = Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS;
  return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (isIos) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: Key("unique_key"),
          child: YourOwnWidget(),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            // your item is swiped, perform operation here
          },
        );
      }
      return GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          // you can show an AlertDialog here with 3 options you need
        },
        child: YourOwnWidget(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```